# What are the important attributes/properties of TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, development-environment, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

What are the important attributes/properties of TextFormField in Flutter can someone tell me?

Comment: Depedns on your need, check [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can study the `constructor` about [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html)

Here is the example of `TextFormField`

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
    labelText: labelText,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "ROCK", color: labelColor),
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
  
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderColor!),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderColor!),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'm not asking for Example. Can you tell me attributes of TextFormFields.??

Answer (score 0):

Also Check TextFormField Properties [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'Hint Text',
    labelText: 'Name *',
  ),
  onSaved: (String? value) {      },
  validator: (String? value) {
    return (value != null && value.contains('@')) ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) TextFormField Properties link is really helpfull.